# Create Multiple .json Files from an Excel file with multiple sheets using Pandas

Tags: json, excel, pandas

I 'm trying to convert a very big number of Excel Files with multiple sheets (some of them very big also) to .json files. So I created a list with the names of the sheets and then made a loop to create a data frame for each sheet and then I wrote this dataframe to a .json file. My code is :

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

file = 'filename.xlsx'

with ZipFile(file) as zipped_file:
    summary = zipped_file.open(r'xl/workbook.xml').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(summary, "xml")
sheets = [sheet.get("name") for sheet in soup.find_all("sheet")]

for i in sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = i, index = False, header = 1)
    json_file = df.to_json(("{}.json").format(i))
```

This code works like a charm when the sheets are not very big. When I run it for an excel file it works and creates the json files I want up to the point that it finds a very big sheet with a lot of data and it crashes. 
So my question is : Is there a different more efficient way to do this without crashing the program. When I run the **df=pd.read_excel** command separately for each sheet it works without a problem, but I need this to happen in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Import `numpy`. Declare an empty `numpy` array, `out_array`. Then, given a list of paths, `paths`, for each path in `paths`, read the file into a temporary dataframe, `temp_df`, get the values of the temporary dataframe using the `.values()` method, store the values into a temporary `numpy` array, `temp_array`, concatenate `out_array` and `temp_array` using `numpy.concatenate`.

Once this loop completes the process, convert the `out_array` to dataframe, `out_df`, using `pandas.DataFrame`. And finally, set column names for your new dataframe.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how is this going to help me. Each file has multiple worksheets with multiple columns each so I need multiple dataframes for each file and for each dataframe to be written in a .json file. From what can I understand on what are you proposing I am going to be working with the file as a whole and not with each worksheet something I can't or need to do. If you could send an example would be of great help . In any case thank you very much for the time you took to give me an answer.